# setInterval in Jquery mobile not working

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to trigger an event every after 10 seconds on a jquery mobile page. But the setInterval() does not seem to work. Also the alert() is displayed even before the page finishes loading.

this is my code

```js
$(document).on("pageshow", function(event) {
  setInterval(update(), 10000);

  function update() {
    alert("Hey");
  }
});
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Include jQuery Mobile stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<!-- Include the jQuery library -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include the jQuery Mobile library -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<div data-role="page" id="chat">
  <div data-role="header">
    <a href="#panel1" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-gear">Options</a>
    <h1>Streamline Chat</h1>
    <a data-ajax="false" href="logout.php" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-power">Log Out</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help please?

Comment: its already working ditto your code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/p9h7d793/7/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only pass the callback to `setInterval`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

```js
$(document).on("pageshow",function(event){
  setInterval(update, 1000);
function update() 
 { 
     console.info("Hey");
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Streamline Chat</title>
<!-- Include meta tag to ensure proper rendering and touch zooming -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Include jQuery Mobile stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<!-- Include the jQuery library -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include the jQuery Mobile library -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="chat">
<div data-role="header">
<a href="#panel1" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-gear">Options</a>
<h1>Streamline Chat</h1>
<a data-ajax="false" href="logout.php" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-power">Log Out</a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check by removing the `()` from `update()` inside the `setInterval`

```
setInterval(update, 10000);
function update() { 
  alert("Hey");
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `update` not `update()` in `setInterval`

```
$(document).on("pageshow",function(event){
setInterval(update, 10000);
function update() 
{ 
   alert("Hey");
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Believe this has already been answered above now, but for future reference or anyone else reading this, here is a little function I wrote to make calling a timeout a little bit tidier:

Function:

```
function timeItOut(time, args, params1, params2){
    setTimeout(function(){
      // add more parameters as per your function with the most params
      args(params1, params2);
    }, time)
}
```

Usage:

```
// Occurs after 4 seconds
timeItOut(4000, animateLights, device);

// Occurs after 7 seconds
timeItOut(7000, scrollScreen, 140);
```

Obviously you can add more 'params' to the timeItOut function, this was just the maximum number of parameters I used in this script.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `requestAnimationFrame`

"why do we just create a `setInterval`? `requestAnimationFrame` has a number of advantages. Perhaps the most important one is that it pauses when the user navigates to another browser tab, hence not wasting their precious processing power and battery life.

```
function update() 
{ 
alert("Hey");
requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
```

Refer [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

[Sample](https://css-tricks.com/using-requestanimationframe/)